# NSMutableUrlRequest not sending proper parameters for HTTP request

Tags: ios, httprequest, swift2, xcode7, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to send a POST request so that a user can login to this app. However, when I try to send the information, the server returns an error message saying that it did not receive the login information. I have used this exact same code before but with the url having HTTPS instead of HTTP. Does swift 2 have a different method that deals with HTTP requests?

In my info.plist file I have added the following:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
 <dict>  
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
 </dict>
```

The api calls work fine on every device except iOS, and the code works fine with a different url. If Swift 2 no longer accepts HTTP requests is there a work around?

```
static let URL = "http://url.com:3000"

static let netSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession() // A shared NSURLSession that will be used to make API calls

// Call to login with the provided credentials. If login is successful the handler function will
// receive 'true', otherwise 'false'.

static func login(email : String, password : String, handler : (success: Bool, error: APIError?) -> ()) {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "\(URL)/users/login")!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let params = ["email":email,"password":password]
    request.HTTPBody = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])

    netSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            handler(success: false, error: APIErrorNetwork)
            return
        }

        let jsonResponse = JSON(data: data!)
        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse

        if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
            // Handle the expected response
        } else {
            handler(success: false, error: APIError(json: jsonResponse))
            print(httpResponse.statusCode);
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: What is being printed in the output console when you execute the request?  Can you add that info as well as the status code?

Comment: Status code = 401. And the error message is 'email' and 'password' required on req.body. So I'm assuming the parameters were never sent

Comment: Try to test the web-service with some desktop REST client app, like CocoaRestClient. With that you will check if web-service is working properly. If yes, then error is in your code. Also, test if HTTPBody is not nil after you set it to the request.

Comment: I tested the web service and it is working fine. HTTPBody is not nil. It is optional value: Optional(<7b22656d ...... 3334227d>)

Comment: Use [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com) to see the exact network http/https traffic.

Comment: `7b22656d ... 3334227d` hex-ascii is `{"em ... 23"}` so that looks like the correct JSON. DId you get this from the code ot from from a network sniffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your server accepts `JSON`? Does it expect you to post form data instead?

If it does expect `JSON`, try to add a `Content-Type` header to your request:

```
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept");
```

Some servers are picky.

Comment: Adding an authorization header worked. I wasn't aware of this. Thank you!